# PHP preg_match_all to match multiple patterns

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

I have a few 10GB files with mysql info which I would like to filter for a specific table.

The queries look like this (though can have fewer or more line breaks):

```
SET INSERT_ID=2/\*!\*/;
at 858735202
121124 12:36:53 server id 1  end_log_pos 0  Query   thread_id=9695754   exec_time=0 error_code=0
SET TIMESTAMP=1663753413/\*!\*/;

            INSERT INTO `bank_accounts_daily`
                (
                    `accounts_bank_md5` ,
                    `accounts_bank_payment_desc` ,
                    `accounts_bank_amount` , 
                    `accounts_bank_number` ,
                    `accounts_bank_sortcode` ,
                    `accounts_bank_currency` ,
                    `accounts_bank_date`,
                    `accounts_bank_code`
                )
                VALUES
                (
                    'zxcvxzcvxzc4c9eeca78908296a2f007',
                    'NAMEJO M        1105294            BBP',
                    '278.50',
                    '645450441',
                    '20-55-19',
                    '1',
                    '26/55/2012',
                    'BBP'
                )
/\*!\*/
```

I am using this, which works to retrieve every single statement:

```
preg_match_all('/(SET INSERT_ID=([0-9]+)\/\*\!\*\/\;)(.*?)(\/\*\!\*\/\;)(.*?)(\/\*\!\*\/)/s', $input, $output);
```

But when I attempt to expand it and add the extra pattern to match specifically the 'bank_accounts_daily' pattern it does not retrieve anything(regardless of backticks being escaped or not):

```
preg_match_all('/(SET INSERT_ID=([0-9]+)\/\*\!\*\/\;)(.*?)(\/\*\!\*\/\;)(.*?)(INSERT INTO \`bank_accounts_daily\`)(.*?)(\/\*\!\*\/)/s', $input, $output);
```

I do not understand why this is not working. I've tried variations without brackets, but nothing is working. Also - are there any potential problems with my approach that I am not seeing?

Comment: You can test your patterns online http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html making it easier to spot mistakes

Comment: Thanks @Waygood, great tool - I tested there - but if I add the extra pattern it still does not work.

Comment: @Barmar has the solution BTW this worked online /SET INSERT_ID=([0-9]+)\/\\\\*\!\\\\*\/;(.*?)(INSERT INTO \`bank_accounts_daily\`)(.*?)\/\\\\*\!\\\\*\//s

Comment: @Waygood - well - it seems to work on that site, but not on my local system.. should I ask a new question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
/(SET INSERT_ID=([0-9]+)\/\\\*\!\\\*\/\;)(.*?)(\/\\\*\!\\\*\/\;)(.*?)(INSERT INTO `bank_accounts_daily`)(.*?)(\/\\\*\!\\\*\/)/s
```

You weren't matching the backslashes in the `/\*!\*/` markers. I don't see how the original regexp could have worked, since it also had this mistake.

Comment: Thank-you @Barmar, there was an error in my test data. The markers should look like **/*!*/** (Sorry for that). This answer does work on the given data on [http://functions-online.com/preg_match.html](http://functions-online.com/preg_match.html) - as does a slight variation on it to suit the correct data - however it does not work on my local system with the real data. It just returns an empty array(though the former answer in my original question does work). Could there be something going on my system? Time for a new question?

Comment: If you correct the test data in the question, I may be able to help.